# Syntax for writing a function defined by cases

Tags: support, mathjax

Suppose we want to write about a function in a question that is defined by cases. In our note books we generally write "$f(x) =$" and then we give a big curly left bracket, and then define various values the function is to take in different domains. How to write this here? I mean can someone give me the syntax?

Comment: Specifically, [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/5025) in the MathJax tutorial thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The environment for that is `cases`, you use it as

```
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & x < 0, \\
                   1, & 0 \leqslant x \leqslant 2, \\
                 -\pi, & x > 2.\end{cases}$$
```

(line breaks and indentation to be adjusted by personal preference, I chose an odd layout here to avoid scroll bars for the code sample) to produce

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & x < 0, \\ 1, & 0 \leqslant x \leqslant 2, \\ -\pi, & x > 2.\end{cases}$$

Comment: Extremely useful. Thank you very much @Daniel Fisher